# Debian 8 : where are default static routes set?

Tags: debian, networking, routing

i'm facing a strange problem with my newly installed Debian 8 box : default static routes are missing the 0.0.0.0 destination route.

```
$ sudo route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.0.0.0        172.18.224.1    255.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.16.0.0      172.18.224.1    255.240.0.0     UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.18.224.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     172.18.224.1    255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

Thus I'm unable to connect to the internet with this setup.

I've checked the interfaces config file and there is nothing wrong here:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

/etc/network/interfaces.d/ is also empty:

```
$ sudo ls /etc/network/interfaces.d/
$
```

I'm lost. Where are the default static routes set ? On every other Linux box I own, everything works perfectly by default. For instance, here is what I get on my Linux Mint box:

```
$ sudo route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.18.224.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        172.18.224.1    255.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.16.0.0      172.18.224.1    255.240.0.0     UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.18.224.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     172.18.224.1    255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

I know I could add the 0.0.0.0 static route to the config of the eth0 interface, but I'd like to understand why it is not there in the first place.

Comment: Could be a problem with your DHCP server? Did you try if other devices can reach the internet?

Comment: Yes, my other devices can connect to the internet perfectly.

Comment: do you have `network-manager` installed?  that grotesque abomination can mess up your network in all sorts of horrible ways.

Comment: Try enabling `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/debug` by setting `RUN=yes`in the script.

Comment: @cas: OK, I did it. What am I supposed to look at now ? And I don't have network-manager installed.

Comment: Try to avoid the deprecated `route` command; it's possible that a default route is setup using policy-based routing. Run `ip route show` and `ip rule show`; if the latter shows any lines with `lookup X` where X is not main or default, run `ip route show table X` for those as well. Add the output to your question.

Comment: Could you confirm if your dhcp-server is configured with `rfc3442-classless-static-routes`, avoiding the `routers` option to be applied to your desktop? - https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=764219. Have you recently upgraded your `isc-dhcp-client` package?